# redux connecting old states

Tags: reactjs, redux

Kind of an interesting problem...

I have a set of components that all use connect to get the state. These components are often children of each other, sometimes deeply nested children.

I want these components to shouldComponentUpdate only when the state changes, otherwise return false. The states are immutable Maps, and I use the is(...)to verify equality. The problem is that when the state changes, some of them see the change, and some of them appear to get an old state, and see no changes. If I complete another action that changes the state, they see the previous state, but not the most recent.

Any ideas? No middleware here.

*Edit... Code. There are a lot of pieces here so bear with me

```
function checkNewState(nextProps, instance){
    return !is(nextProps.state.reducerName, instance.props.state.reducerName)
}

const StupidParent = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps){
        return checkNewState(nextProps, instance)
    },
    render: function(){
        return <p>{this.props.state.reducerName.get('name')}
            {this.props.replace(this)}
        </p>
    }
})

const StupidChild = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps){
        return checkNewState(nextProps, instance);
    },
    render: function(){
        return <p onClick={changeStateNameProperty}>
            {this.props.state.reducerName.get('name')}
        </p>
    }
})

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {state}
}

export const Parent = connect(mapStateToProps)(StupidParent);
export const Child = connect(mapStateToProps)(StupidChild);


<Parent replace={(parent)=>{
    return <Child />
}} />
```

Comment: Without some code, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: I figured it out. I thought my code was just relying states, but my code was also relying on props (that were generated by the state, but would only be generated after the state was updated, which would not trigger the shouldComponentUpdate) GAH

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but check if you use the parameter of the function shouldComponentUpdate and not the "this.prop" or "this.state" from your component. The current props/state will give you the old props/state. The new prosp/state is in the import parameters like nextProps/nextState.

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  return nextProps.id !== this.props.id;
}
```